# Sequelize-CLI: Running a migration

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

When I am running a migration on this class I want to be able to assign an id and a UUID. Setting the id as primary key and the UUID with a defaultvalue. However, when I run the `sequelize db:migrate` command I'm getting the highly vague error:

> val.replace is not a function:

Here is my code:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
 const projects = sequelize.define('projects',
  {
   id: {
    type: Sequelize.UUID,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
    unique: true
  },
  uid: {
    type: Sequelize.UUID,
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,

  },
  client: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING(255),
    allowNull: false
  },
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING(255),
    allowNull: false
  },

},
{
  tableName: 'projects',
  freezeTableName: true,
  underscored: false,
  // don't forget to enable timestamps!
  timestamps: true,
  // I don't want createdAt
  createdAt: 'dateCreated',
  // I want updatedAt to actually be called updateTimestamp
  updatedAt: 'dateModified',
  // And deletedAt to be called destroyTime (remember to enable paranoid for this to work)
  deletedAt: 'dateDestroyed',
  // Paranoid will not delete tables from cascade only add delete to active

});

  return projects;
};
```

Comment: is it similar to https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/6016

Comment: Keval thanks for the guidance on this, it's exactly what I was looking for.